# Error: Instance does not have a volume attached at root (/dev/sda1)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

Getting error while starting ec2 instance after attaching volume:
I have defined device_name as "/dev/sda1" but it still picking up "/dev/sdf".

Here is my code:

```
ec2_vol:
      instance: "{{ instance_id }}"
      id: "{{ ec2_vol.volume_id }}"
      device_name: "/dev/sda1"
      region: "{{ aws_region }}"
```

Comment: Did you try naming it `/dev/xvda1` ?

Comment: What is being returned when you run `lsblk` on the aws instance?

Comment: Its showing NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  40G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0  40G  0 part /

Comment: I changed device_name: /dev/xvda1, but still smae error is showing. I saw it is taking "/dev/sdf" as device. Don't know why?

Comment: So, you are trying to replace a root volume? Isn't it easy to launch a new instance with the newly created volume?

Comment: No, its not my requirement. I have to apply it only on existing instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111555/discussion-between-kohi-and-ravitezu).

Answer (score 18):

With /dev/sda1 won't work anymore (at least in my case, I replaced a gp2 root volume for a magnetic one) and had to specify directly xvda (without /dev) on the device field.

So, in the field Device: xvda

That's it.

(well, seems a transient issue and related only to debian instances, this happened in Oregon region, I tried it in Ireland and you got to specify /dev/sda1 as usual)

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for me on a Debian instance on EU-Frankfurt.

Comment: let me reinforce that is just xvda and NOT /dev/xvda that may sound more intuitive

Comment: this actually works just fine ... i was not able to find it anywhere as part of the documentation! saved my day!

Comment: Same here, it seems to be specific to Debian instances.

Comment: It didn't work for me. But after many attempts, I was able to set again `/dev/sda1/`. Not sure why. Oregon region.

Answer (score 15):

You need to detach the volume and then reattach the same to EC2. And also while attaching Volume make sure you specify Device as /dev/sda1.

Please follow below step by step Procedure for the same:
[Link](https://linuxroutes.com/how-to-resolve-instance-does-not-have-a-volume-attached-at-root-dev-sda1-error/)

Comment: Your bad link does not provide any new information and is fill with non technical data, also how can you have positives with an incorrect and misspelled device name???

Comment: Just a small typo: it is `/dev/sda1`

Answer (score 11):

Seems there have been changes in AWS.  In May 2020  I had an instance which had a 10 GB EBS volume attached as root disk, as "/dev/sda1"

While stopped I misclicked and detached the root disk, then immediately reattached it as /dev/sda1.   Sunsequently a boot failed with this error:

[image: Own screenshot]
 "Instance does not have a volume attached at root (xvda)"

The solution was right there in the error - I had to detach the root EBS volume and reattach it as just **xvda**  that is without any /dev/ and without a partition number.  At that point the instance was prepared to boot.

Comment: This happened to me as well.

Comment: For me, set  Device: /dev/sda1 worked, and Device: xvda doesnt.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use aws cli:

```
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-abcde12345678901e --instance-id i-acdef123456789012 --device /dev/sda1
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/attach-volume.html#examples

Comment: This worked for me and I think it should be recommended !

Comment: Worked for me in 04/2022, the issue seems to be a limitation from the Web UI/logic, this is was better.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this works differently for literally everyone, so let me add my 2 cents and describe what worked for me.

I had attached my root volume as (literally) `sda1` because that is the format described on the "attach volume" page, however, as the error message above suggests, it is looking for a device name that is literally `/dev/sda1`.

Detaching and re-attaching my root volume as `/dev/sda1` (vs. `sda1` or `xvda` as described in the example) solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to run the instance, it suggested the volume is not attached as root (/dev/xvda1). So I went to volume and re-attached it as /dev/xvda1 to that instance to make it work.

Comment: if you add '/dev/' won't work, just: 'xvda' with no device number

Answer (score 1):

Go to the volumes section (under the Elastic Block Store), right click on your volume, attach, select your instance, then type /dev/sda1 in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 is looking for literally same name of volume to be attached, so just by detaching the volume and reattaching with expected name (mentioned in the storage section of instance) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If encountering this issue in 2024 and doing it from AWS console management, while modifying the EBS volume, the "device name" field caption will guide you to additional details. Follow the provided instructions, and the volume will be modified accordingly to that specified root name. [image: when you modify aws volume]

Answer (score -1):

With /dev/sda1 won't work anymore (at least in my case, I replaced a gp2 root volume for a magnetic one) and had to specify directly xvda (without /dev) on the device field.

So, in the field Device: xvda
[image]